# how to get laravel single locale string in blade template?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-localization

This is my message.php file which in my locale file.Code are given bellow.

```
return [
    'title' => 'This is Bangla Page',
];
```

Now i want to retrieve my string 'This is Bangla Page' . How to do that.
I use blade templating and write `@lang('messages.title')` but it shows me Array to string conversion error.

Comment: try `@lang('message.title')`. Your file is `message.php` not `messages.php`

Comment: first you should set your app_locale in your config/app.php then use `{{trans("messages.title")}}` in your view